# C# projects: objects cross-usage

Tags: c#, .net, reference, namespaces

Have 2 projects: MyServer & MyClient in one solution. Want to use object of Message class which is in both projects (MessageServer & MessageClient respectively). 
I added reference of the client to the server project, but cannot do the opposite because I get error *"...would cause a circular dependency"*. So I have

```
using TestMyClient;

namespace TestMyServer
{
    public class MessageServer
    {
```

on the server side and then I use it in the code `= new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestMyClient.MessageClient));`

I want to have the same, but on the client side. Sadly I cannot input the `TestMyServer` as `using` namespace and thus I cannot reference the `MessageServer` class...

How to cross-use these classes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear - it's not obvious why you'd want to have two different types at all - but the answer is to have *one* type in a namespace which both the server and the client projects refer to.

```
Server     Client
   \        /
    \      /
     Common
```

No circular dependencies, *one* shared type, everyone's happy.

If you actually need two message types (one for requests and one for responses, for example) then define both messages in the Common project. I would advise that you *don't* call them `MessageServer` and `MessageClient` though - both messages will be used by both the server *and* the client, as one will generate it and the other will consume it. Using the terminology of request and response is generally a lot clearer.

Comment: Okey, using common object makes a lot sense. Thanks. :) 
But what if I need to apply cross-usage in some other case in future. Then I would get stuck on the same problem, probably?

Answer (score 1):

In general: if you have two 'things' that depend on functionality of the other (circular dependency), then extract the common functionality into a third thing. Let both existing things reference the new third thing.

When those things are classes, e.g. `MessageServer` and `MessageClient`, then extract the common functionality into the `Message` class and let the original two classes derive from the new class.

When those things are projects, e.g. `AwesomeServer` and `AwesomeClient`, then extract the common functionality (e.g. the `Message` class) into a new `Awesome` project and let the original two projects reference the new project.